# template for handling user defined type and structure

Tags: c++, templates, structure

I'm trying to define a template that can handle user defined types and structures. The issue so far is that I can not get information of the structure members through the type definition. The template is suppose to detect structure data type and handle different member types accordingly.

The solution I came up so far involves a vector of type strings that signal the member element count and type:

```
std::vector<std::string> typeList
```

The program then traverse the list and handle structure according to typeList. There is so far no checking against given structure at all so behavior is undefined if a different structure is passed in.

My question is that is there any elegant way that can achieve this? I'd prefer the solution to check the incoming structure itself to get such type list information instead relying on a second data structure.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: You want to receive a struct type and then enumerate its member types?

Comment: What if the structure is complex?  i.e. has other complex structures as member types.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yes, in a sense. I'm trying to create a universal data sink that can handle such structures and convert all C types to corresponding types in a second language with given APIs. Enumerate member types can help achieve this as a mediate method.

Comment: @Trenin I have thought of this. I'm thinking if the type is unknown, try apply same template function on the member recursively. This should handle nested structures but not sure the impact on other cases.

Comment: C++ does not provide any reflection allowing you to enumerate members and members like in java. But you could use template specialization to either implement the method for every type or have the type provide some informations about itself by providing static methods (due to duck typing / templates, can be used like an interface)

Comment: @Paranaix My plan is to use template specialization to handle different types while doing the parsing. Nevertheless, the point I'm stuck is the stage member data type needs to extracted. With the interface user calling the template function, how does the function know how many members in the structure? If there is nay nested structure, how does it know they are there?

Comment: @Xephon You genuinely can't do it. You need to think of a different approach. Maybe somebody could help you think of on approach if you explained why you need this.

Comment: The function simply does not know, there is no way to find out in c++ except some static analysis of the code (combined with code generation)

Comment: @JosephMansfield I'm creating an interface between general C/C++ structures to ErLang terms for better communication between a C node and ErLang node. That's why I need to parse the structure, generate corresponding terms and struct the tuples according to original structure topology. I also want to hide all these bulky stuff from user so give a clean C/C++ interface for easier adaptation. This is as much I can describe regarding the usage.

Comment: @Xephon And there is nothing more we can tell you that this is simply impossible. The only way is to use code generation using some external tools during the compilation process.

Comment: @Paranaix I understand to achieve this I will require users to program in a given manner so I can parse the code in run time. Your solution might just work as guys using the interface should be okay adapting a programming rule involving templates and class inheritance. Let me try this out. I'll let you guys know if this actually pans out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is **template specialization**.

E.g we could write a `serialize` method which is implemented differently for specific types:

```
template<typename T>
void serialize(const T& val)
{
     static_assert("No implementation for this type provided");
}

template<>
void serialize<std::string>(const std::string& val)
{
    // std::string specific implementation here
}
```

Notice that partial specialization (specialization for mutli types) is only possible for class templates.

There is no way to inspect types genericaly (like in java or c#) but you can have your types providing informations on their own.

```
template<typename T>
class GenericSerializeable {};

struct Foo : public GenericSerializeable<Foo>
{
    int bar;

    static std::vector<std::string> GetMembers()
    {
        return {"bar"}; // we could of course return a more complex type here providing more informations
    }

};


// lets assume for a moment here that partial specialization is possible for functions, this is just a proof of concept
template<typename T>
void serialize(const GenericSerializeable<T>& type)
{
    for (auto name : T::GetMembers())
    {
        // do whatever you want with them here
    }
}
```

The combination with template specialization and a "tag class" allows is to treat types aswell not providing this interface with the same function signature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm well aware of template specialization. What I want is to "parse" an arbitrary type, possibly defined with `typedef struct {...} T;`, and process all member of the structure accordingly.

Comment: @Xephon notice that there was a little mistake in my implementation, please have another look at it